# Can the same html page host two Rocket.Chat livechat widgets?

Tags: rocket.chat

I have a single page application where I want to host two different LiveChat widgets from two different rocket chat instances. Is it possible?

Comment: Maybe here ? https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/multiple-instances-to-improve-performance/

Comment: This talks about having multiple instances so that the performance can be improved. What I am looking for is to have separate embedded channels served from different domains